# Check if session is still valid with Cookies [JSession, SMSession]

Tags: java, swing, cookies, httpurlconnection

I´ve got a browser for my Swing application where I browse to a single sign in page. After login, I save the JSession and SMSession Cookie for further communications with this server via httpurlconnection. After some idle time, the server will delete this session and I have to make a new login and generate new cookies. How do I check if the session is still valid?

Here is my approach:

```
URL url = new URL("www.exampleurl.com");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+session+"; SMSession="+smsession);
System.out.println(conn.getRequestProperties());

conn.connect();

if(conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    System.out.println("connection failed");
    session = null;
    smsession = null;
} else {
    System.out.println("connection fine!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a while back.

Siteminder protected resources have max idle and max session timeouts.

Everytime you make a call to a siteminder protected site, you get an updated SMSESSION cookie. You need to make sure you keep updating the smsession. This will solve the idle timeout.

For max session timeout, you will get a redirect with some specific values in the query string. Your code can detect the redirect (302) and evaluate the URL.

Having said all that, you can ask the siteminder admins to pass the timeout values to you in a cookie and you can keep track of it from there.

Hope that helps.
Pasha